# Why do we calculate the length of the scan line on a CD disc using $\frac{\mathrm{area~ of~ the~ disc}}{\mathrm{between~ 2~ scan~ lines}}$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-kinematics

For a situation akin to the one described in part b of this question:

[image]

For its as the follows, I am wondering why we are solving for scan line using the area of the disc?

[image]

I thought that the scan line would look like the purple lines in the following picture:

[image]

Then, maybe we can approximate them as circles that are $1.6 \mu m$ apart, and add up the circumferences of these circles:

[image]

Thus, I have trouble understanding why we are solving the problem as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you imagine you uncoiled the scan line into a long straight line, its area would be (length of line) $\times$ (width of line).

When the scan line is on the disk, its area = the area of the disk.

You could solve the problem by adding up the areas of all the circles as in your post, but (1) that is a lot more work and (2) it is still only approximate, because each turn of the scan line is actually part of a spiral, not an exact circle.

Comment: Thank you! Just a quick follow-up question, we are still making an estimation when pretending that the extended area is a rectangle, right? It seems to me that one side of the extended rectangle will be longer than its opposite side (since its the outer sides of the circle), thus, it doesn't seem to me that it's a regular rectangle.